# User management system similar to wordpress one?

Tags: php, users, mysql, login, user-registration

I am in very big need of a user management system just like the one that wordpress uses but without being blog related. I need to be able to manage users and apply certain privileges depending on user level. I tried to take apart the WP engine and take out the users part but I think it's so tied to the whole engine, I wasn't able to... Does anyone know of any scripts that offer the same register, login etc functions? Also, could it be open source? I already bought my first user management system but it sucks really bad... :(

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me.
Andy

Comment: try [backpress](http://backpress.org/features/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can still use WordPress and disable the front end functionality, or like @OneTrickPony suggested you can try  [**BackPress**](http://backpress.org/) which is a PHP library of core functionality for web applications that grew out of WordPress.

Comment: +1 Just to add one line: The backpress system is a _sister_ of wp, but comes without any UI.

Comment: thank you very much! I will try this and see how it works. Consider this question closed.